# Checking current scene name using SceneManager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've decided to split my game into separate scenes(main menu, gameover, etc.) And I'm trying to use an if statement in my code to check if the current scene is "gameover" so I can perform some action. I know Unity now uses SceneManager instead of Application, but what's the equivalent of this function

```
 if(Application.loadedLevelName == "gameover")
```

I've tried `SceneManager.GetActiveScene == "gameover"`
But I just get errors like can't use == here. 
I have imported SceneManager aswell

Comment: You would get more focused answers to this on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an error here because [`SceneManager.GetActiveScene()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene.html) returns an object of type `SceneManager.Scene`, not a string. However, [according to the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.html), this gives you access to the public `Scene.name`, which is a string.

So the non-deprecated equivalent of:

```
if (Application.loadedLevelName == "gameover") {
    // ...
}
```

Would be:

```
if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "gameover") {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Completely forgot that it returned an object. Appreciate the help!